# PowerShell: Trying To Get Desktop and Documents Folder Sizes

Tags: powershell

Hey guys I've been asked to find out from all the workstations in my environment, how much space users are using on their Desktop and Documents folders.  I figure PowerShell should be able to tell me this information, and I have a script that kinda-sorta does what I want it to, but it's not robust enough.  Here's what I came up with:

```
# This collects the user running the script's Documents folder size.
$DocumentsSize = (Get-ChildItem $env:USERPROFILE\Documents -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)

# This collects the user running the script's Desktop folder size.
$DesktopSize = (Get-ChildItem $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)

# This converts the Documents folder size to GB with 1 decimal place and outputs the result.
$DocumentOutput = "Documents {0:N1}" -f ($DocumentsSize.sum / 1GB) + " GB"

# This converts the Desktop folder size to GB with 1 decimal place and outputs the result.
$DesktopOutput = "Desktop {0:N1}" -f ($DesktopSize.sum / 1GB) + " GB"

# This writes the output of the Documents folder size calculation to a file in the current user's Documents folder as their username.txt
$DocumentOutput | Out-File $env:USERPROFILE\Documents\$env:USERNAME.txt -Append

# This writes the output of the Desktop folder size calculation to a file in the current user's Documents folder as their username.txt
$DesktopOutput | Out-File $env:USERPROFILE\Documents\$env:USERNAME.txt -Append
```

And that's all well and good for a single user outputting to a file in their Documents folder.  What I need to do is run this from say, a Domain Controller such that it will parse every workstation in a CSV file that I have with a header of "HostName" and output the results to a new CSV file in such a way that we get the amount of space the Desktop and Documents folders are each taking up and include the usernames associated with those values.

The more I dig into this, the more I realize 2 things: 1) this request is WAY beyond my meager PowerShell scripting skills and 2) some more advanced commands are needed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: FWIW I'd use `"Documents {0,7:N1} GB" -f ($DocumentsSize.sum / 1GB)`

Comment: Why?___________

Comment: Right aligning numbers, simplicity of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all users from specified machine with listing content of C:\Users folder. Then simply repeat your steps for each of them.

```
foreach ($Comp in (Get-Content 'hosts.txt')) {
    foreach ($UserFolder in (Get-ChildItem "\\$Comp\c$\Users" -Directory)) {

        $DocumentsFolder = Join-Path ($UserFolder.FullName) 'Documents'
        $DesktopFolder = Join-Path ($UserFolder.FullName) 'Desktop'

        $DocumentsSize = (Get-ChildItem $DocumentsFolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        $DesktopSize = (Get-ChildItem $DesktopFolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)

        $DocumentOutput = "Documents {0:N1}" -f ($DocumentsSize.sum / 1GB) + " GB"
        $DesktopOutput = "Desktop {0:N1}" -f ($DesktopSize.sum / 1GB) + " GB"

        $FileName = Join-Path $DocumentsFolder (($UserFolder.Name)+'.txt') 
        $DocumentOutput | Out-File $FileName -Append
        $DesktopOutput | Out-File $FileName -Append

    }
}
```

Couple of issues here:

- Output is always appended, so it might be good to either delete file on each run, or add some time stamp to the file. If you want to store it at some other/central location, just play with $FileName
- You might need to play with users root folder if you want to cover all cases. Not on every machine it would be C:\Users. Google for Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile

Comment: I tried your version and got the following error:

Measure-Object : The property "length" cannot be found in the input for any objects.
At C:\Users\wparga\Documents\foldersize.ps1:7 char:69
+ ... tem $DocumentsFolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Measure-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GenericMeasurePropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand

Comment: OK, thats possible if there are no files, just folders or nothing. You need to ignore this error by adding ErrorAction, as dividing by 1 GB will convert it to proper value of 0. I will update the code above.

Comment: Oh this is so close!  I modified the Out-File command to point to a network location where I want the results stored, and that part works.

It works, but I need the output to indicate which computer it's on as well.  Like the output filename having the computer name in it as well.  Like computername.username.txt or something like that.  I hate asking for so much help.  I'm just not that good at PS yet.

Comment: GOT IT!  I also managed to get it to output to a single file (which is what I wanted in the first place.  Now I just gotta figure out how to output it to a CSV instead (my boss will want a spreadsheet anyway).

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter.  I can import it into a spreadsheet as a space delimited file.  Thank you SO much for your help!

Comment: One more thing: I don't understand the need/usage for the .FullName part after the $UserFolder variable and the .sum part after the $DocumentsSize and $DesktopSize variables. Can you explain those to me?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I wanted to both thank @Kamikaze Duck for getting me started and post the revised/improved code I just created. This code will output a CSV file in the directory you run the script from, best to run in PS as administrator on a DC. It also includes Pictures/Music/Videos and formats the output to be readable and condensed:

```html
$FileNameDate = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"
$OutFileName = ".\UserFolderStorage_" + $FileNameDate + ".csv"

$CSV_Header = '"Computer Name","User Folder","Documents (GB)","Desktop (GB)","Pictures (GB)","Music (GB)","Videos (GB)"'
$CSV_Header | Out-File -Encoding ascii $OutFileName

Get-ADComputer -Properties Name -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} | ForEach-Object { 
    $Comp = $_.Name
    if (Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $Comp -Quiet) {
         foreach ($UserFolder in (Get-ChildItem \\$Comp\C$\Users -Directory)) {

         echo "Processing $UserFolder on $Comp"

         $DocumentsFolder = Join-Path ($UserFolder.FullName) 'Documents'
         $DesktopFolder = Join-Path ($UserFolder.FullName) 'Desktop'
         $PicturesFolder = Join-Path ($UserFolder.FullName) 'Pictures'
         $MusicFolder = Join-Path ($UserFolder.FullName) 'Music'
         $VideosFolder = Join-Path ($UserFolder.FullName) 'Videos'

         $DocumentsSize = "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem -Path $DocumentsFolder -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1GB)
         $DesktopSize = "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem -Path $DesktopFolder -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1GB)
         $PicturesSize = "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem -Path $PicturesFolder -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1GB)
         $MusicSize = "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem -Path $MusicFolder -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1GB)
         $VideosSize = "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem -Path $VideosFolder -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1GB)

         $SummaryOutput = '"' + "$Comp" + '","' + "$UserFolder" + '","' + "$DocumentsSize" + '","' + "$DesktopSize" + '","' + "$PicturesSize" + '","' + "$MusicSize" + '","' + "$VideosSize" + '"'
         $SummaryOutput | Out-File -Encoding ascii $OutFileName -Append

         }
    }
    else {
         echo "$Comp NOT RESPONDING!"
         $SummaryOutput = '"' + $Comp + '","N/A - NOT RESPONDING","","","","",""'
         $SummaryOutput | Out-File -Encoding ascii $OutFileName -Append
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the finalized code I'm using.  The resulting file is a flat text file that I am able to import into a spreadsheet as a space delimited file, and it works great.

```
foreach ($Comp in (Get-Content 'C:\full_path_to_the_source_file\hosts.txt')) {
    foreach ($UserFolder in (Get-ChildItem "\\$Comp\c$\Users" -Directory)) {

        $DocumentsFolder = Join-Path ($UserFolder.FullName) 'Documents'
        $DesktopFolder = Join-Path ($UserFolder.FullName) 'Desktop'

        $DocumentsSize = (Get-ChildItem $DocumentsFolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        $DesktopSize = (Get-ChildItem $DesktopFolder -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)

        $DocumentOutput = "$Comp $UserFolder Documents {0:N1}" -f ($DocumentsSize.sum / 1GB) + "GB"
        $DesktopOutput = "$Comp $UserFolder Desktop {0:N1}" -f ($DesktopSize.sum / 1GB) + "GB"

        $DocumentOutput | Out-File \\Some_Server\Share\Results\Results.txt -Append
        $DesktopOutput | Out-File \\Some_Server\Share\Results\Results.txt -Append

    }
}
```